# Transaction recovery in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Does DynamoDB supporting in transaction recovery and how transaction recovery in dynamodb work?

I had search in document of dynamodb and google and i not found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such thing as a transaction recovery in DynamoDB. Transactions in DynamoDB are ACID compliant, but if you need to roll back a transaction then you would have to do so manually.